# Classicthesis chapter number gets black

Tags: color, chapters, classicthesis

[image: Image is here]

The chapter number is black, but it should be light gray. I have not modified anything in the layout files and have downloaded fresh one. Has anyone got a clue where I can change to adjust the color back to light gray?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Yes, would have to come back to this tomorrow. However, if anyone has experienced this before, it would save me some trouble.

Comment: Well, I don't know if somebody has experienced this before, but I think you can save them the trouble of guessing what is happening in your code. But, well, there is always tomorrow. `:)` BTW, [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm sorry, the object of this site isn't "to save me some trouble", but "to allow me to be part of a community where we can all help each other to solve our common problems and improve our knowledge".

Comment: The problem was with XeTex, it seems that using something else fixes the problem! If anyone has a suggestion for the best graphics driver, it would be great.

Answer (score 3):

This is the code that `classicthesis` uses to set the chapternumber:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\relax}{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}%
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
```

There are no options in `classicthesis` to alter the colour of the chapter number, so unless you changed it in those lines, one of your packages and/or changes are responsible for the black number.

You could add the following to your preamble, which would "reset" the original code at the beginning of the document. So if you (or one of your packages) are responsible for the black colour, this should reset the changes.

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
        {\relax}{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{halfgray}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}%
        {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]%
}
```

Note that this is not a fix. A fix would be to construct an MWE in order to find out how the error occured in the first place.